# Hibernate Auto-Increment Non-ID column

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have a column "val" lets say, which is **not an id column** and I want to set it as auto-increment. Is there any way I can do that with a Hibernate/JPA annotation?

Comment: would you consider store procedure ? this way sound like this is not the best practice .... why do you need it ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way. Annotate the auto-generated field with [@Generated](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Generated.html), to let Hibernate know that it has to re-read the entity after an insert and/or update to get the value of the generated value.